# Mcafee PCI Compliance failing on Session ID cookie?

Tags: drupal, cookies, pci-dss

I am attempting to obtain PCI compliance for my site but the Mcafee security scan has thrown a:

`Potential Sensitive Persistent Cookie Sent Over a Non-Encrypted (SSL) Channel`

Drupal (default behavior) sets a session cookie when you simply arrive at the site.  This is causing the problem.  Clearly, the entire site shouldn't be under SSL; plenty of other sites set session cookies like this.

What gives?

Comment: re "what gives": what exactly are you asking here?

Answer (score 0):

What version of Drupal?

You might consider the [Pressflow](http://pressflow.org/) fork of Drupal, which backports some fixes from Drupal 7 to earlier versions. One of the notable ones is that it doesn't set a session cookie for anonymous users unless they actually need one. Assuming you don't need the cookies, you might be able to sidestep this whole problem.